# Getting error while deploying the database project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, deployment, database-project

I am trying to deploy the database project using start option. But it giving me below error :
**"Error    12  SQL72045: Script execution error"**

At the time of publish it get properly reflect the changes.

Comment: What is the line that gives the error? You should be able to click or double-click the error to go directly to the line in the .sql script that gave the error.

Comment: GO
**CREATE VIEW [dbo].[LinkedServerEmployee]**
Also for
**CREATE LOGIN [dbproj]**